# Multiple query with while loop using array to output to textarea

Tags: arrays, while-loop

I want to select 2 columns from my table and have an array output the individual entries into multiple textareas (repeating).

So far I have:

```
$query= "SELECT comment FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15";

$result=mysqli_query($con, $query);

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{


echo '<textarea>';
echo  $row['comment'];
echo '</textarea>';
echo '<p></p>';

}
```

The above works great outputting the comment into individual boxes but I can't figure out how to get the date too.
    I'm trying to have comment boxes display each with their own comment from the database but I also want the date it was posted which is 'when'(timestamp) in my table.

I have tried "SELECT comment,when FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15";
and I have tried merging array and doing $row[]  and declaring each variable but maybe I got the syntax wrong. I've tried a lot of things actually including using an image and div but to no avail. This php file is being included onto a html page. I am very new to this. Any help and I would be grateful.

Comment: Please post the code you tried to get the dates, and the error you got.

Answer (score 0):

Your Select statements only contains the `comment` column. You need to have:

```
SELECT comment, when FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15
```

and then in your code you can do:

```
....
echo $row['when'];
....
```

I would suggest renaming your `when` column to `data_entry_date` or `date_created`

Comment: Yeah thanks...I already tried that and it didn't work. I have tried it again but I think maybe the problem is at the database settings because I get no error but it doesn't add the date. I have it set as timestamp,Attributes= ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, Null NO, Default = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, Extra=on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: Thanks...I have fixed it by changing it to echo date("m/d/y",strtotime($date_created)); but i wouldn't have even thought to look in that direction without your help.

Comment: I can't as it says you need reputation 15 to do that. It was helpful.

Comment: @TeaDrinker you need 15 rep to upvote, but you can accept an answer whenever, even if you have 0 reputation. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work